# send to the user welcome email after registration in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to send to the user welcome message after registration, but it did not send anything to the email, but the data is inserted in the database
can you please help me figure out what is wrong with my code

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];    
 $query2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO facultymember (pin,ID,firstname,midname,lastname,phone,email,password,Door_Num) Values('".$_POST["type"]."','".$_POST["FMID"]."','".$_POST["firstname"]."','".$_POST["middlename"]."','".$_POST["lastname"]."','".$_POST["phone"]."','".$_POST["email"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["Door_NUM"]."')", $connection);
     $message = "Add Successfully";

if($query2)
{

$subject = "Email Verification mail";
$headers = "From: email@domain.com \r\n";
$emessage = "welcome";
mail($email,$subject,$emessage,$headers);
}
```

Comment: Have you configured the mail server to use etc?  Are you hosting it yourself or elsewhere?

Comment: no i have not done this

Comment: Then that is the problem.  You need to configure the mail function in php.ini.

Comment: do we need to discuss the issues about using mysql_query (old and deprecated) and the security issues about inserting the Post variables directly in to the DB. Swap to PDO and use prepared statements with bound variables

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
$to      = $email; // Send email to our user
$subject = "Email Verification mail"; // Give the email a subject 
$emessage = "welcome";

// if emessage is more than 70 chars
$emessage = wordwrap($emessage, 70, "\r\n");

// Our emessage above including the link
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: no-reply <noreply@yourdomain.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion(); // Set from headers

mail($to, $subject, $emessage, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Comment: Walaikumalsalam, thank you for your help, but it did not work

Comment: but it worked fine to me. it may be server error . contact your server admin. or if you host your site yourself then try configure emailing system correctly.

Comment: bro try edited code please and then see results. please give feedback

Comment: the problem still occurs

Comment: did you delete if($query2){}